# PyQtGraph when show in a different screen misalign axis

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? On my desktop screen this is how the plot looks like:

[image: Plot on desktop screen]

However once I drag the graph to my monitor the points become misaligned and the axis is not complete.
[image: Plot on monitor screen]

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue and for me it was related to using screens with a resolution > 1920x1080. In my case (using Windows) the problem could be solved with:

```
import platform
import ctypes
if platform.system()=='Windows' and int(platform.release()) >= 8:   
    ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(True)
```

other possible fixes are `QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)` and `os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"`.

There are even more possible solutions, as for example [here](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/756#issuecomment-505949584).

Comment: Nice -- thanks @fischmalte. How did you....find this relatively obscure solution out?

Comment: I don't remember, maybe I saw it in some GitHub issue or so 